# Apply logic to multiple rows of pandas' groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider a data frame `df`

```
    date      time   isopen    isclose  openlate   closeearly
    20200201  0920   Y         N        Y          N
    20200201  1645   N         Y        N          Y 
    20200202  0900   Y         N        N          N
    20200202  1650   N         Y        N          Y 
    20200203  0910   Y         N        Y          N
    20200203  1700   N         Y        N          N
```

`openlate` and `closeearly` were computed from time and `isopen/isclose` columns.

I would want to flatten by date, to have something like

```
    date      openlate   closeearly
    20200201  Y          Y
    20200202  N          Y 
    20200203  Y          N
```

Basically to collapse multiple rows by a `groupby`, partition or window function, then choose a logic which value to keep among the rows. I do have this situation on many occasions.

```
    df.groupby("date")..['openlate' take 'Y' if any df["openlate"] in group is 'Y', else 'N';
 'closeearly' takes 'Y' if any df["closeearly"] in the group is 'Y', else 'N']
```

Comment: Why is there an `isopen` and `isclose` column? Isn't one column enough to capture that information?

Comment: This is part of the story. There are rows between open time and close time. Entries such as 12h30 will have **isopen** and **isclose** as 'N'. This analysis focus on open and close time only.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use named aggregation `.agg`

```
df1 = df.groupby('date').agg(
openlate=('openlate','first'),
closeearly=('closeearly','last'))

print(df1)

         openlate closeearly
date                        
20200201        Y          Y
20200202        N          Y
20200203        Y          N
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the logic of 'first' and 'last' ? How do you pass the logic as function to **.agg** in a more generic situation ? For example in the group, if column isAccepted has the number of 'Y'  > 2 times number of 'N', and the median of column **value** > 100, then return 'Pass' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method. It allows you to apply a custom function to aggregate each group. In fact it even allows you to pass a dictionary mapping each column to a different function.

In your case:

```
df.groupby('date').agg(any)
```